# How to refer to all IPs using an IP Range e.g. XX.XX.XX.XX / 24

Tags: networking, ip

How can I refer to all IPs using an IP Range e.g. XX.XX.XX.XX / 24?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are looking for.

Comment: The syntax you've used is usually known as CIDR notation.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Do you want a mask that covers the entire IPv4 address space? That would be `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: this works in google cloud sql public ip